# Azure Batch Job Schedule - notification after recurrence job completed/failed

Tags: azure, schedule, azure-batch

I am trying to use Azure Batch Job Schedule in my application with .Net core. I want to get some notification/event trigger once the recurrence job is completed/failed in the job schedule so that I can copy output files to storage and send email to the end-user.

Is it possible to get such notification from azure Batch job schedule or is there any solution to this?
I can't find any sample implementation of Azure Batch job scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this blog will sove your problem: https://mindmajix.com/azure-batch

Step by step example with code has been provided

Batch Tutorial 
Here we will use dot net batch library and visual studio to create a sample batch task.
Step 1. Create containers in Azure Blob Storage.
Step 2. Upload task application files and input files to containers.
Step 3. Create a Batch pool.
3a. The pool StartTask downloads the task binary files (TaskApplication) to nodes as they join the pool.
Step 4. Create a Batch job.
Step 5. Add tasks to the job.
5a. The tasks are scheduled to execute on nodes.
5b. Each task downloads its input data from Azure Storage, then begins execution.
Step 6. Monitor tasks.
6a. As tasks are completed, they upload their output data to Azure Storage.
Step 7. Download task output from Storage.

Comment: Azure Batch Job Scheduling: https://kiltandcode.com/how-to-use-azure-batch-job-schedule/